# Razor partial destroys Japanese text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a page which loads a footer element in razor like this: `@Html.Partial("Footer")`
My footer element contains some Japanese text and some links.

When the page is rendered, the Japanese text is missing some encoding or something. If I place the text directly in my Layout file, it renders as it should. So like this:
[image]

So somehow the `@Html.Partial()` is destroying the text.
I tried to encode my text in the Footer, but no luck.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you explicitly save the partial as UTF8?

Comment: @Sascha you mean on the disk? I use VS, and Im not sure how VS save the file, but I think the saving is ok, because it works in the Layout file.

Comment: depending on how the file was created, it might have been created with a different encoding. I believe that VS will preserve the encoding instead of overwriting it to UTF8

Comment: @DLeh hm good call. I will try to re-create the file in VS to be sure.

Comment: @DLeh Sascha thank you to both of you! It was a wrong encoding on the file. I recreated the file in VS, and now it works like a charm! Could one of you create an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will not overwrite the encoding on a file. So if it was created with the incorrect encoding, Visual Studio will continue to save it with that encoding.

Changing the encoding on the file to UTF8 or recreating the file with the correct encoding should resolve the issue.